# read first element in array

Tags: awk, osx, defaults

```
defaults read -g AppleLanguages
```

produces something like this:

> (
>      en,
>     de
>   )

I'd like to extract just the first element, in this case "en",

```
defaults read -g AppleLanguages | awk '/\(/ , /,/'
```

but awk always includes the search patterns. What can I do to produce just "en"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just print the second line. You can use many tools for this:

- `sed`

  ```
  defaults read -g AppleLanguages | sed -n '2s/,//p;' file
  ```

  **Explanation**: The `2` means "run the following commands only on the second line". The `-n` suppresses normal output (nothing is printed unless explicitly told to do so). The substitution (`s///`) deletes the comma and the `/p` at the end prints the lines where the substitution occurred.
- `perl`

  ```
  defaults read -g AppleLanguages | perl -ne 's/,// && print if $.==2'
  ```

  **Explanation**: Remove the first comma (`s/,//`) and print the line if the current line number (`$.` is 2. The `-n` means "read the input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.
- Unix tools

  ```
  defaults read -g AppleLanguages | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | tr -d ,
  ```

  **Explanation**: `head -n 2` prints the two first lines, `tail -n 1` prints the last one (therefore, the second of the file) and `tr -d ,` deletes commas.
- `awk`

  ```
  defaults read -g AppleLanguage | awk 'NR==2{sub(",","");print}'
  ```

  **Explanation:** `NR==2{}` means "run what's in the brackets only on the second line. `gsub(",","")` deletes the first comma.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
awk -F, '/[^(]/{print $1;exit}'
```

Explanation:

- `-F,`: treat `,` as field separator
- `[^(]`: for lines that contain at least one non-`(` character.
- `print $1; exit`: print first field and immediately exit the `awk` (so only first line which matches the pattern will be printed)

Comment: Another, probably better option is `awk -F, 'NR==2{print $1}'`.

Comment: @terdon Thanks very much for your enlightening answers. As far as I know the output from AppleLanguages is never empty if it exists. If you only have one language enabled to start with `defaults read` will complain that the "domain/pair of [...] does not exist".